# How do I make it so that my application homepage defaults to user sign up, instead of sign in using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I am using Rails 3 and devise and am trying to make it so that when a person comes to my web app, they are taken directly to the user registration sign_up link instead of the sign in link.

I'm pretty sure that I'm having this problem because my routes are configured like:

```
root :to => "babies#new"
```

Accessing the baby model requires a user to be logged in. To get around this I've tried changing this to:

root :to => "users#sign_up"

It doesn't seem to work? I get an error saying that I have an:

```
uninitialized constant UsersController
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions is to create separate controller say `main` and an action in it `sign_up_redirect`. Then configure your routes file like this:

```
root :to => "main#sign_up_redirect"
```

and write in that action next:

```
redirect_to new_user_registration_path
```

* path to registration can be different to you

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://gist.github.com/1312293 . I feel like I might be getting something wrong.

Comment: Emm, in general yes, but I am not sure about `Parents` constant you pass to the method `new_registration_path`, btw: does `new_registration_path` is the proper method name for registration url?

Answer (score 0):

The following error happens when the corresponding controller is not found. You should check whether you are having UsersController or UserController

```
uninitialized constant UsersController
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are scoping the Devise routes, `root :to => 'users#sign_up'` doesn't exist. I would also highly recommend against setting any Devise route as your root as all of the Devise hooks redirect to root ie. `after_sign_up`, `after_sign_in`, `after_update`. I think that for the desired outcome you have two options.

First would be to simply put a sign up form on the page at your root url. You can follow the logic in [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app) tutorial to accomplish this, obviously changing from sign in to sign up.

The second option that comes readily to mind is to create a passthrough controller that simply has an index action that redirects to the sign up page. Something like that could look like this.

```
class PassthroughController < ApplicationController

  def index
    redirect_to 'devise/registrations#new'
  end

end
```

Either option is simple enough to implement.